# Possible to change the colour of the indentation guide lines per indentation level?

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

I can change the indentation guide line colour as shown in this image (the green lines):
[image: Current one]

I'd like to have the colour be different per indentation level, to help with code inspection and reading. Similar to this poor edit. Alternatively if it was per scope that'd be even better, i.e. the 2 for loops at the same indenation level would have different colour indentation lines.

[image: Edited one]

Anybody know if this is possible in IntelliJ/Android Studio?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The color of the vertical indent guide can be changed in IntelliJ IDEA when you go to Preferences > Editor > Colors & Fonts > General, then select the list item “Vertical indent guide”. [See this Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjscG.png). Tested on Mac OS X with IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 14.1.4.

Comment: Not really quite what I wanted, but I guess it answers most peoples question, so I'll accepted it.

Answer (score 0):

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10080-rainbow-brackets

this plugin shows color guide lines and much more related

for all JetBrains products

[image]